# Datastage Sequence job- how to process each file at a time if those files are in 7 different folders

Tags: unix, datastage

DataStage -  There are 7 folders in a path and in each folder there are 2 files . for eg : the 2 files are in the folllowing format- filename = test_s1_YYYYMMDD.txt, test_s1_YYYYMMDD.done. The path for these files are user/test/test_s1/
user/test/test_s2/
...
...
..
user/test/test_s7/------here s1,s2...s7 represents the different folders

In these folders the 2 above mentioned files are present , so how can i process each file in a sequence job?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a job to process a file and the filename needs to be a parameter of that job.

For the Sequence level you need two levels - the inner one for the two files within each folder and a outer one for the different directories.

For the inner one you can choose to build a loop with to iterations or simply add the processing job twice to the sequence (which will reduce complexity in case it will always be two files).

The outer Sequence is a loop where you could parameterize the path in a way that the loop counter could be used to generate your 1-7 flexible path addon.

Check out more details on loops [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/r_ddesref_Start_Loop_Activity_Properties.html)

You can use the loop counter (stage_label.$Counter) to parameterize your job.

Comment: Hi Michael 
I got the flow , since I'm new to dataStage can you please explain the flow in detail, so it will be very helpful

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the  files, it is an important decision how to process your files. Starting a job (or more) in a sequence for each file can lead to heavy overhead for just starting the jobs. Try loading all files at once in a parallel job using the sequenial file stage.

In the Sequential File Stage, set the appropriate Format. You can also set everything to none to just put each row in one column and process that in a later job. This will make the reading very flexible and forgiving. If your files are all the same structure, define your columns as needed.

To select the files, use File Patterns. In the Options of the Sequential File Stage, choose to have a File Name Column so you can process the filenames in a later job. You might also want to add a Row Number Column.

This method works pretty fast.

[image: Sequential File Stage reading files from a folder structure]
[image: Column Format Settings]
[image: Columns]