# DataStage- How to Parameterize a file Pattern in a sequence job using user variable stage and execute command stage

Tags: datastage

I have to parameterize a list of files of a specific pattern

For Eg: the pattern of the files is given as test_t?*data*????????.txt

I have to parameterize this file name in datastage using user var stage and execute command stage for every time I run the jobs

Comment: I answered quite exactly that in your last question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66652613/datastage-sequence-job-how-to-process-each-file-at-a-time-if-those-files-are-in  Use a Sequencer File Stage to avoid most problems.